# convert ds.Tables[1].Rows[0].ToString() to int

Tags: c#

I can't convert `ds.Tables[1].Rows[0].ToString()` to an int.

```
ds.Tables[1].Rows[0] = 100;
```

Gives an error can't convert.

Comment: You're going to need to post more code than this if you want an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string test = Convert.Int32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["YourIntegerColumn"].ToString())
```

If your column isnt an integer, then it's not gonna work, so you'll probly want to check if the column is null, then check if its parsable to an int using `Int.TryParse`

Answer (score 3):

ds.Tables[1].Rows[0] returns a DataRow. You need to indicate the column that you want to assign the value:

```
ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Your column name"] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the column?
ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][column] = value;